# Updating one column field generates a relationship bug

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I need help to understand why I get this message when I only update a column field with entity framework.

The operation failed: The relationship could not be changed because one or more of the foreign-key properties is non-nullable. When a change is made to a relationship, the related foreign-key property is set to a null value. If the foreign-key does not support null values, a new relationship must be defined, the foreign-key property must be assigned another non-null value, or the unrelated object must be deleted.

I never update the foreign keys within my model but only an integer field which count the view per page.

Here is my code:

```
// Service
...
Tender currentTender = base.GetById(tenderId)
currentTender.ViewCount = currentTender.ViewCount + 1;
base.UpdateSpecificFieldsOnly(currentTender, views => views.ViewCount);

// Repository
        public bool UpdateSpecificFieldsOnly(TEntity entityToUpdate, params Expression<Func<TEntity, object>>[] includeProperties)
        {
            if (entityToUpdate == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentException("Cannot add a null entity.");
            }

            try
            {
                var id = this.dbSet.Create().GetType().GetProperty("Id").GetValue(entityToUpdate);

                this.dbSet.Attach(entityToUpdate);
                foreach (var includeProperty in includeProperties)
                {
                    context.Entry(entityToUpdate).Property(includeProperty).IsModified = true;
                }

                return true;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return false;
            }
        }

public virtual bool Save(bool shouldValidateEntity = true)
        {
            try
            {
                context.Configuration.ValidateOnSaveEnabled = shouldValidateEntity;
                context.SaveChanges();
                return true;
            }
        }
```

Thank you for your help. On this one, I don't know where to start..

Karine

Answer (score 0):

I think you pretty much overdoing it. If I understood you right, that you are trying to do should be simple as this:

```
// replace "EFDbContext" with your EF context class
using (var context = new EFDbContext()) 
{
    // replace "Id" with your primary key column name for tender
    var currentTender = context.Tenders.Single(t => t.Id == tenderId);
    currentTender.ViewCount = currentTender.ViewCount + 1;
    context.SaveChanges(); 
}
```